# Ansible file manipulation

Tags: ansible

I have an xml file with multiple interface entries. 
I would like to be able to change the mac address for eth2 but not for eth0

```
<interface type='direct'>
  <mac address='52:54:10:cc:28:73'/>
  <source dev='eth2' mode='passthrough'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<interface type='direct'>
  <mac address='52:54:b3:85:b4:25'/>
  <source dev='eth0' mode='vepa'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

Playbook looks like this at this point:

```
 tasks:
  - name: modify the mac address for eth2
    lineinfile: dest=/tmp/mactext backup=yes
      insertbefore='      <source dev=\'eth2\' mode=\'vepa\'/>'
      line='      <mac address='52:54:10:cc:28:73'/>'
```

Comment: You have stated what you want. You have not stated what your problem is. Those files look perfectly fine to me. Is that the way you want them to look?

Comment: My Question is how do I change the eth2 mac address using ansible in the above file. I have tried "change' and 'lineinfile'

Comment: The lineinfile and template modules will both handle these fine. What is your exact issue with using lineinfile to do this? Can you post your playbook/role?

Comment: updated with my attempt of a playbook

Answer (score 0):

The [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/blockinfile_module.html) should be your solution. See the exapmles for your use case.

```
- name: insert/update eth0 configuration stanza in /etc/network/interfaces
    (it might be better to copy files into /etc/network/interfaces.d/)

  blockinfile:
      dest: /etc/network/interfaces
      block: |
        iface eth0 inet static
            address 192.168.0.1
            netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: this will work great for the interfaces file but i need t also update the xml file.